# The Value of type 'Boolean' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.DataRow"

Tags: vb.net

am getting an error 1 message that states "The Value of type 'Boolean' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.DataRow". How do I convert a value type Boolean to System.Data.DataRow? Have tried but to no avail.

Here's my code

```
Dim newRow As DataRow

newRow = Database51DataSet1.Tables(0).NewRow
newRow.Item(0) = TextBox3.Text
newRow = ("orderID") = (TextBox3.Text.Trim() = "0"(Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text)))
newRow.Item(1) = TextBox4.Text
newRow.Item(2) = TextBox5.Text
Database51DataSet1.Tables(0).Rows.Add(newRow)
```

Comment: Could you explain what are your intentions in the fourth line of your code above?

Comment: Next time, please tell us on which line you are having the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to convert a boolean to a `DataRow`. The compiler assumes that because the comparison returns a `Boolean` and you assign that to `newRow`.

I think you want to assign the `OrderId` field value. So replace...

```
newRow = ("orderID") = (TextBox3.Text.Trim() = "0"(Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text)))
```

with

```
Dim orderId As Int32
If Int32.TryParse(TextBox3.Text.Trim(), orderId) Then
    newRow("orderID") = orderId
End If
```

Which also handles the case that it's not a valid integer.

If that column is actually a `string` and you want to assign the value with a leading zero:

```
newRow("orderID") = TextBox3.Text.Trim().PadLeft(2, "0"c)
```